# How to auto remove extra spaces around the content in vue template by eslint

Tags: vuejs3, eslint, eslint-plugin-vue

I want to find a eslint rule, likes below, I tried some rules, but not works

```html
<div class="label">  content  </div>
```

Hope to auto remove the spaces around the content

```html
<div class="label">content</div>
```